# How to make a method return a two dimension array of type double in c

Tags: c, matrix, inverse

I have a method in c for computing the inverse of a three by three matrix, this method returns a 2 dimension vector of the type double,I declared a 2 dimension vector variable in my code and tried to assign but when i try to get the elements of the inverse 2 dimension vector, the code does not print anything

***Code to compute the Inverse of a 3 by 3 matrix***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>

double Determinant(double matrix[2][2]){
    double det=0;
    double a =matrix[0][0];
    double b=matrix[0][1];
    double c=matrix[1][0];
    double d=matrix[1][1];
    det=a*d-b*c;

    return det;
}
double** inverseMatrix(double matrix[3][3]){
    //define the entries for the matrix of minors
    double m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9;
    //get the members of the matrix
    double a=matrix[0][0];
    double b=matrix[0][1];
    double c=matrix[0][2];

    double d=matrix[1][0];
    double e=matrix[1][1];
    double f=matrix[1][2];

    double g=matrix[2][0];
    double h=matrix[2][1];
    double i=matrix[2][2];

    //fill in the matrix of minors
    m1=(e*i)-(h*f);
    m2=d*i-g*f;
    m3=d*h-g*e;
    m4=b*i-h*c;
    m5=a*i-g*c;
    m6=a*h-g*b;
    m7=b*f-e*c;
    m8=a*f-d*c;
    m9=a*e-d*b;

    double minorArray[3][3];
    minorArray[0][0]=m1;
    minorArray[0][1]=m2;
    minorArray[0][2]=m3;
    minorArray[1][0]=m4;
    minorArray[1][1]=m5;
    minorArray[1][2]=m6;
    minorArray[2][0]=m7;
    minorArray[2][1]=m8;
    minorArray[2][2]=m9;


    //get the determinant //DEFINE THE MATRICES TO USE FOR THE DETERMINANT
    double A[2][2];
    A[0][0]=e;
    A[0][1]=f;
    A[1][0]=h;
    A[1][1]=i;

    double B[2][2];
    B[0][0]=d;
    B[0][1]=f;
    B[1][0]=g;
    B[1][1]=i;

    double C[2][2];
    C[0][0]=d;
    C[0][1]=e;
    C[1][0]=g;
    C[1][1]=h;

    double det=a*Determinant(A)-b*Determinant(B)+c*Determinant(C);
    int index=0;
    //get the matrix of co-factors
    for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
            index+=1;
            //check for entries at odd indices and negate them
            if(index%2!=0){
                minorArray[row][col]=-1*minorArray[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
    double answer[3][3];
    //divide everything by the determinant
    for(int row=0;row<3;row++){
        for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
            answer[row][col]=minorArray[row][col]/det;
        }
    }
    //determinant is given by a*DET(MA)-b*(DET(MB)+c*DET(MC
    double** ans= (double **) answer;
    return ans;
}
```

After that I try to assign the result of the method above to a variable I declared in the main, and then print out the elements of the inverse of the three by three matrix but my code outputs nothing

```
//assigning vaues to the matrix
 int kk=10;
    double test[3][3];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            test[i][j]=kk;
            kk--;
        }
    }
//declare a 2d vector as pointer and assign the result of the method
 double** answer=inverseMatrix(test);
    //print out the elements of the function
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("%.f  ",answer[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do this in c and how do I get my code to successfully print out the members of the inverse matrix?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates "code outputs nothing".

Comment: Here `double** ans= (double **) answer; return ans;` you return a pointer to a local variable. Don't. Change that and then demonstrate that your code "outputs nothing". I still do not get how the code does not output anything. But in order to avoid all kinds of nasty stuff, aka nasal demons, aka UB, please fix that fundamentally broken part before we even discuss what exactly you have observed.

Comment: Its an MRE, the longer code is a method to compute the inverse in case no one noticed

Comment: @Yunnosch, how do I make it return a two dimension array to the variable, I think that is my problem, am updating the post though

Comment: I propose to focus your question on returning a 2D array. Or search for that beforehand....

Comment: I saw some article on the site suggesting use of structs but I was confused

Comment: If you think that "Its an MRE" then you did not understand the concept as described in the link. [mre].

Comment: Also, you **can not** refer to an actual 2-dimensional matrix such as `double matrix[3][3]` with a `double **`.  Matrices are **NOT** pointers - if anyone told you that "a matrix is a pointer" they are flat-out wrong.  Pointers are variables that **hold** an address.  Matrices are variables that **have** an address.

Comment: You say "I have a problem. I know what to do: I will use a cast, like this: `double** ans= (double **) answer;`!" And now you have two problems.

Comment: Returning matrices from function with an actual `return` statement might not be a very good idea. Existing mainstream linear algebra packages accept a pointer to the result, and fill the pointed-to array. There are various good reasons to follow this style.

Comment: Last but not least, you are using caveman's methods to compute the inverse and the determinant. It is fine to do so for an exercise, but not for any actual work. There are much better ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you wrap your matrix arrays into structs, different struct for different sizes. Here's one:

```
struct Matrix3 {
    double m[3][3];
};
```

---

Let's also add some constants for convenience, a global (static or extern) variable:

```
const struct Matrix3 ZeroMatrix3;  // globals are implicitly initialized to 0
const struct Matrix3 IdentityMatrix3 = { { 
    { 1, 0, 0}, 
    { 0, 1, 0},
    { 0, 0, 1} } }
```

---

Your inverse function might become:

```
struct Matrix3 inverseMatrix3(const struct Matrix3 * restrict mp){
    struct Matrix3 result = ZeroMatrix3;

    // dummy code which does nothing:
    result = *mp;

    return result;
}
```

Example use:

```
struct Matrix3 input = { { 
    { 1, 2, 3}, 
    { 4, 5, 6}, 
    { 0, 0, 0} } };
struct Matrix3 inverse = inverseMatrix3(&input);
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
        printf("%.f  ", inverse.m[i][j]);
    }
}

struct Matrix3 secondIdentity = inverseMatrix3(&IdentityMatrix3);

// you probably want to add a compare function at some point...
assert(compareMatrix3(&secondIdentity, &IdentityMatrix3)); // verify that inverse of identity works
```

---

The point here is, define simple structs which holds your matrixes. You may want to add more structs, like `struct Vector3` and `struct Matrix3x1` and so on, what ever you need. Then you can return them from functions using values, and assign them with `=` directly, and so on.

You could also pass them as values, but here they are passed as pointers to const struct, which is generally more efficient. That being said, 2x2 matrix is 32 bytes and 3x3 matrix is 72 bytes, and copying such small amount of bytes is very fast, so in general trying to optimize using pointers to heap allocated matrixes might even slow things down, and definitely add a lot of hassle. The use of [`restrict` keyword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) here is a small optimization, you don't really need to care about it if you don't want to.